# Python Logic - Simplify/more efficient multiple if elif statements

Tags: python, if-statement

[I'm taking an Intro to Python course online](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/9-else-and-or-not/) and would like to solve this problem more efficiently.

> The words 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th, 8th, 9th are called ordinal adjectives. Write a program which reads an integer x between 1 and 9 from input. The program should output the ordinal adjective corresponding to x. 
>   Hint: you don't need to have 9 separate cases; 4 is enough.

```
x = int(input())
if x == 1:
   print("1st")
elif x == 2:
   print("2nd")
elif x == 3:
   print("3rd")
elif x == 4:
   print("4th")
elif x == 5:
   print("5th")
elif x == 6:
   print("6th")
elif x == 7:
   print("7th")
elif x == 8:
   print("8th")
elif x == 9:
   print("9th")
```

I can't figure out how to write this more efficiently in four lines. Does it involve lists? They have not taught lists or arrays yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
x = int(input())
if x == 1:
   print("1st")
elif x == 2:
   print("2nd")
elif x == 3:
   print("3rd")
else:
   print(str(x)+"th")
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use string formatting. And account for different suffixes between 1, 2, 3, and the rest of the numbers

```
x = int(raw_input())
if x == 1:
    suffix = "st"
elif x == 2:
    suffix = "nd"
elif x == 3:
    suffix = "rd"
else:
    suffix = "th"
print "{number}{suffix}".format(number=x,suffix=suffix)
```

You could actually do it in a more pythonic manner with a mapping instead of an if/else block

```
x = int(raw_input())
suffix = {1: "st", 2: "nd", 3: "rd"}.get(x, "th")
print "{number}{suffix}".format(number=x, suffix=suffix)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why convert to `int`?

```
x = input()
if x == "1":
    print("1st")
elif x == "2":
    print("2nd")
elif x == "3":
    print("3rd")
else:
    print(x+"th")
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed my function to go above 9, but none of the answers were exactly what I needed. I came up with this and thought I'd share. I know it's not the most elegant solution, but it worked for what I needed it to do.

```
def ordinal_adjective(n):
    if ('%s' % (n,))[-2:] in ['11','12','13']:
        return '%sth' % n
    elif ('%s' % (n,))[-1] == '1':
        return '%sst' % n
    elif ('%s' % (n,))[-1] == '2':
        return '%snd' % n
    elif ('%s' % (n,))[-1] == '3':
        return '%srd' % n
    else:
        return '%sth' % n

x = input()
print ordinal_adjective(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't do switch case statement in python, but you can use these examples to do it in a different way, not necessary better:

- [here](http://bytebaker.com/2008/11/03/switch-case-statement-in-python/)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Comment: It might be useful to add a short summary for each.

Comment: If you add a summary, your post could continue to be useful after your links go dead. :)